# Good way to share configuration data across multiple Lightning Components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We are doing some work soon where multiple Lightning Components all need to access some JSON configuration data. Is there a good pattern that allows this data to be read once from the server and injected into the (fairly independent) components?

For example, one component could do the read and fire an application event containing the JSON configuration that all components then consume.

If you have any good working patterns for this situation, please share...

Comment: Did you consider using Static Resources to hold the JSON config? You could reference them in each component.

Comment: @Folkert I hadn't - good idea. Would you expect browser caching to apply so multiple references would only result in one download?

Comment: Yes, static resources are cached

Comment: Just put it to the test in a lightning component that just loads a static resource and placing that component on a record page a few times. It only loads the static resource from cache once (or if you clear cache only downloads once).

Comment: @Folkert Thank-you for doing that. For me the data was going to be in a static resource anyway. Most static resource reference examples are to images or JavaScript to execute: if there is simple to pull the content into a JavaScript `var` from the URL then I'll certainly accept that as the answer.

Comment: Yea there is, let me whip something up as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Static resource are cached and can be referenced in multiple places in your Lightning Component. I'm assuming you want to do use it directly in your JS controller, but it's also possible to reference Static Resources in component markup (for instance for CSS style sheets).

Referencing Static Resources multiple times on the same page (for instance in multiple Lightning components) will result in just 1 call to the browser cache or 1 download of the static resource.

Use the [$Resource value provider](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_resource_value_provider.htm) to reference the Static Resources in your Lightning Component.

```
({
    useJSONFromStaticResource: function(component) {
        var json = $A.get('$Resource.JsonStaticResource') + '/assets/jsonconfig.json';
    }
})
```

Comment: Mmm, looks like it only gives you a reference to the Resource, instead of the reference itself. Have to look into it further.

Comment: Yeah hopefully there is a simple approach to getting the content.

Comment: I guess XMLHttpRequest (OK with Locker Service I presume as listed here http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/index.app?aura.mode=DEV) but IE11 looks a problem based on https://caniuse.com/#search=XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Eventually support for IE11 is going to be discontinued, so don't know if that's going to be a huge blocker. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_browsers_sfx.htm&type=0

Comment: Unfortunately we have enterprise customers who are still locked into IE11 because of other "legacy" systems that require it.